# MySQL PDO LastInsertID after insert with "before" trigger returns wrong value

Tags: mysql, lastinsertid

I have a customers table with ID (auto_inc), name, ... and customer_code fields. This table has also a "before" trigger, the select one customer code from another table, and set the customer_code field before insert a new record in this table. Works perfectly.

The problem is that when I retrive the lastInsertID() it always return 1 !

I'm using PDO and PHP.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does your table have auto incremented primary key?

Comment: And if you remove trigger then everything works fine?!

Comment: YES... my project did work for months without any problem, until I have to include the costumer_code field using "before" trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of MySQL are you using?  Since 5.0.12, the last insert id shouldn't be overwritten by a trigger.  But before that version, a trigger could change the value and subsequent queries would see the wrong value.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines-last-insert-id.html